# How to pass data (which am getting from server) into tableView which is in UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have one viewController. In that i have one button, if i click on that button am presenting a UIView on that viewController.
In that UIVew i have one tableView. Now i want to pass data into that tableview, which am getting from server.
I cant display the data in tableView, i kept breakpoint and checked. am not able to enter into **cellForRowAt indexPath** method also
could any one help me with this

Here is the code which i tried

Here is my UIView class

```
class ButtonClicked: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        //super.awakeFromNib()
    }
```

Here is my ViewController class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var tableviewDisplayArray: NSArray = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        buttonClicked.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: “TableViewDisplayCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: “tableViewDispCell")
        buttonClicked.tableView.delegate = self
        buttonClicked.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    @IBAction func addMoneyButtonClicked() {
        buttonClickedWebserviceCall()
        actionAlertViewController.actionType = ActionAlertType.ADD_MONEY
        present(self.view.actionAlertPopup(alertVC: actionAlertViewController), animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }
    func buttonClickedWebserviceCall(){        
        let params: NSDictionary = ["langId" : “1”,  "countryId" : “1”]
        callingWebservice().dataTaskWithPostRequest(urlrequest: URL_BUTTONCLICKED viewcontroller: self, params: params) { (result, status) in
            let response : NSDictionary = result as! NSDictionary
            let status = response.value(forKey: "httpCode") as! NSNumber
            if status == 200{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableviewDisplayArray= (response.value(forKey: “response”) as? NSArray)!
                    print(self.tableviewDisplayArray)
                    self.buttonClicked.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                }
            }
        }
    }//method close
 }//class close

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == buttonClicked.tableView {
        return tableviewDisplayArray.count
        }
        else{
            return 5
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if tableView == buttonClicked.tableView {
            return 30.0
        }
        else{
            return 75.0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == buttonClicked.tableView {
            let cell = buttonClicked.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewDispCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewDisplayCell
            let  storedArray = self.tableviewDisplayArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
            print(storedArray)
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “normalCell”, for: indexPath) as! NormalCell
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the TableView Visible when displayed? A UItableView won't draw its contents if the frame isn't visible.

Comment: where have u created object for ButtonClicked view??

Answer (score 0):

You have written the tableView delegate methods in an extension of UIViewController class. Just write that code inside the ViewController class where you have set the delegate and datasource to.Like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
var tableviewDisplayArray: NSArray = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    buttonClicked.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: “TableViewDisplayCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: “tableViewDispCell")
    buttonClicked.tableView.delegate = self
    buttonClicked.tableView.dataSource = self
}
@IBAction func addMoneyButtonClicked() {
    buttonClickedWebserviceCall()
    actionAlertViewController.actionType = ActionAlertType.ADD_MONEY
    present(self.view.actionAlertPopup(alertVC: actionAlertViewController), animated: animated, completion: nil)
}
func buttonClickedWebserviceCall(){        
    let params: NSDictionary = ["langId" : “1”,  "countryId" : “1”]
    callingWebservice().dataTaskWithPostRequest(urlrequest: URL_BUTTONCLICKED viewcontroller: self, params: params) { (result, status) in
        let response : NSDictionary = result as! NSDictionary
        let status = response.value(forKey: "httpCode") as! NSNumber
        if status == 200{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableviewDisplayArray= (response.value(forKey: “response”) as? NSArray)!
                print(self.tableviewDisplayArray)
                self.buttonClicked.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            }
        }
    }
}//method close
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == buttonClicked.tableView {
    return tableviewDisplayArray.count
    }
    else{
        return 5
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView == buttonClicked.tableView {
        return 30.0
    }
    else{
        return 75.0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == buttonClicked.tableView {
        let cell = buttonClicked.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewDispCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewDisplayCell
        let  storedArray = self.tableviewDisplayArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        print(storedArray)
        return cell
    }
    else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “normalCell”, for: indexPath) as! NormalCell
        return cell
    }
}
//Notice that tableView delegate methods should be in your ViewController class because that is the 'self' here so delegate and datasource is the ViewController class
//buttonClicked.tableView.delegate = self
//buttonClicked.tableView.dataSource = self
//as you write this the tableview looks for data in this ViewController class.
//Extensions are meant for another purpose.
}
//class close
```